# SQL Developer show the schema prefix

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

SQL Developer show the schema prefix

i.e in package name now showing prefix will loading the sql developer

Comment: SQL Developer Tool need to know the option to show the prefix

Answer (score 0):

When browsing the contents of the Oracle Database, in this case PL/SQL programs, we show you the code that's stored in the database.

We add onto that,
'CREATE OR REPLACE'

We do not, add the schema prefix.

[image]

If I make changes to this and hit COMPILE, we maintain the schema (HR2) for you, even though I'm logged in as HR.

If you want the PL/SQL code with the schema prefix attached, use the DDL command.

[image]

If you maintain your source code in files and open said files in Oracle SQL Developer, you'll of course see the schema prefix in your code, assuming you put it there.

Comment: Thanks Thatjeffsmith my question let's take you an example I have created hr2.proc_do_nothing when going to the Procedures script check it is not showing a prefix in the script. Some time back there is some options Tools --> Preferences?

Comment: You won't ever see that, no there's no preference. I've explained above. If you have an actual script/file, then you'll see whatever you put in there, but when loading from the database, you won't.

Comment: yes, i need will load the database to get the prefix name?  so it is not possible in sql developer tool